# How do I find the ID of a unique element for a dynamic button that displays profile info in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a unique user info when the mouse of the user hovers over a button, a unique information page is displayed. This page is a unique div element with a specific ID, which is assigned to the button when the button gets added onto the page dynamically. I am struggling with getting the ID of the info div. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the HTML code where you will be able to see 2 different buttons with 2 different div element named friend_info1 and friend_info2 which are the elements I am trying to get the ID of:

```
<button type="button" class="friend-button" id="friend-button1" onmouseover=displayInfo(this)>
    <div class="media">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="mr-3" alt="Default Picture" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Friend1</h5>
            <p>status: active</p>
        </div>
</button>
<div class="friend_info" id="friend_info1" onmouseover="getUserInfo(this);">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="backgroundInfo" id="backgroundInfo">
        <source src="Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="profile-picture" alt="Default Picture" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="p-2">
                <h1 class="Friend_Name">Friend1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="p-1">
                <h5>status: active</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="p-9">
                <p class="info">Name: Joesdadsadsadsadsa</p>
                <p class="info">Surname: Smithdsadsadsadsadsa</p>
                <p class="info">Phone Number: 07914836605</p>
                <p class="info">Gender: Male</p>
                <p class="info">Date of birth: 14/02/2003</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<button type="button" class="friend-button" id="friend-button2" onmouseover=displayInfo(this)>
    <div class="media">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="mr-3" alt="Default Picture" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Friend1</h5>
        <p>status: active</p>
    </div>
</button>
<div class="friend_info" id="friend_info2"  onmouseover=getUserInfo(this)>
    <video autoplay muted loop class="backgroundInfo" id="backgroundInfo">
        <source src="Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="profile-picture" alt="Default Picture" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="p-2">
                <h1 class="Friend_Name">Friend1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="p-1">
                <h5>status: active</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="p-9">
                <p class="info">Name: John</p>
                <p class="info">Surname: Smithers</p>
                <p class="info">Phone Number: 07567836505</p>
                <p class="info">Gender: Male</p>
                <p class="info">Date of birth: 04/12/2000</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript for which I need the unique ID for. Remember, I cannot use getElementById as the id changes accordingly to which button I am hovering:

```
var friend_button = document.getElementById("friend-button");

function displayInfo(button){
  const position = button.getAttribute("data-position");
  var friend_info = document.getElementById(`friend_info${position}`);
  var coords = button.getBoundingClientRect();
  var coordsOfInfo = $('.backgroundInfo').width();
  var subtractWidth = coords.left-coordsOfInfo;
  friend_info.style.left = subtractWidth+"px";
  friend_info.style.top = coords.top + "px";
  friend_info.style.display = "block";
  button.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
  friend_info.style.display = "none";
});
};
```

I have tried creating a function that gets the ID of the div element when hovered however I was getting returned a null value evertime I hovered over the element (You can see my attempt in the html code above with the "getUserInfo(this)".

```
function getUserInfo(information) {
  console.log(information.id);
  return information.id;
}
```

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are trying to do here. Do you mean that when hovering on `friend-button1`, you wanted to get the id of `friend_info1`?

Comment: Yes that is correct. When friend-button1 is hovered, I want friend-info1. When friend-button2 is hovered, friend-info2 is displayed and so on.

Comment: I am not sure how you wanted to proceed with the code, thus I have provided a suggestion on how you can get the respective `friend_info` element. 
If you wanted to proceed with `getUserInfo(this)` method, I have also fixed your code to return the id.

Comment: Thank you very much. looking through the code now and implementing it to see if it works like I want it to. You are correct by the way, the friend_infoX will always be in that format and the number will always  be the same as the button's number.

Comment: Do the divs already exist when the buttons are dynamically added? When the button gets added onto the page dynamically is the button id based on the div id? Maybe seeing the code that adds the buttons would help, if it's not too hairy.

Comment: I am currently on a web development course and I haven't been tought PHP yet so I don't have the code that adds the friends yet. I will learn PHP tomorrow so I will be able to start coding the logic behind the add friend button. The div elements will be created with the button when a friend gets added. In the past, I tried to make the information of the friends a seperate HTML file but that didn't succeed, so I made it how it is currently. Any tips as to what I should do once I implement the code would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve. There are few ways to do it.

This method is that assuming that `unique user info` element id are in a fixed format as such `friend_infoX` where the `X` is the numbering. If this is the case, then you can add a custom attribute to the button `data-position` and set the numbering as the value. By this way, you can dynamically set and use the `getElementById` to access the respective user info.

```js
function displayInfo(button){
    const position = button.getAttribute("data-position");
    var friend_info = document.getElementById(`friend_info${position}`);
    var coords = button.getBoundingClientRect();
    var coordsOfInfo = $('.backgroundInfo').width();
    var subtractWidth = coords.left-coordsOfInfo;
    friend_info.style.left = subtractWidth+"px";
    friend_info.style.top = coords.top + "px";
    friend_info.style.display = "block";
    button.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    friend_info.style.display = "none";
  });
};
```

```css
.friend_info{
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="friend-button" id="friend-button1" data-position="1" onmouseover=displayInfo(this)>
    <div class="media">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="mr-3" alt="Default Picture" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h5 class="mt-0">Friend1</h5>
            <p>status: active</p>
        </div>
</button>
<div class="friend_info" id="friend_info1">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="backgroundInfo" id="backgroundInfo">
        <source src="Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="profile-picture" alt="Default Picture" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="p-2">
                <h1 class="Friend_Name">Friend1</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="p-1">
                <h5>status: active</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="p-9">
                <p class="info">Name: Joesdadsadsadsadsa</p>
                <p class="info">Surname: Smithdsadsadsadsadsa</p>
                <p class="info">Phone Number: 07914836605</p>
                <p class="info">Gender: Male</p>
                <p class="info">Date of birth: 14/02/2003</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<button type="button" class="friend-button" id="friend-button2" data-position="2" onmouseover=displayInfo(this)>
    <div class="media">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="mr-3" alt="Default Picture" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">Friend2</h5>
        <p>status: active</p>
    </div>
</button>
<div class="friend_info" id="friend_info2">
    <video autoplay muted loop class="backgroundInfo" id="backgroundInfo">
        <source src="Background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="d-flex">
        <img src="default-pic.png" class="profile-picture" alt="Default Picture" width="200" height="200">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="p-2">
                <h1 class="Friend_Name">Friend2</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="p-1">
                <h5>status: active</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="p-9">
                <p class="info">Name: John</p>
                <p class="info">Surname: Smithers</p>
                <p class="info">Phone Number: 07567836505</p>
                <p class="info">Gender: Male</p>
                <p class="info">Date of birth: 04/12/2000</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Besides, for the function `getUserInfo(this)`, you can simply get the element id by doing as such:

```
function getUserInfo(information) {
  //var gettingId = document.getElementById(information); //You dont need this
  console.log(information.id);
  return information.id;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error at `friend_info.style.left = subtractWidth+"px"`  saying friend_info is null. Any clue as to why this may be the case?

Comment: whenever you get `null`/`undefined` means the element is not referred. Maybe you could update your question with your latest code. It is hard for me to tell what is going on without having a look on the codes. As on the above example I gave, there's no error on `friend_info.style.left = subtractWidth+"px"` when try to run the code snipet.

Comment: got it. I will update the question.

Comment: I updated the question to include the code you implemented. Hopefully you will also get the same error and can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Found my error. I didn't update the html to include the 'data-postion' tag. I did and now it works. Thank you for the help